# How to make ChartJS not cut off tooltips?

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I am trying to figure out how to make [chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) not cut off it's tooltips, but I can't seem to find a config option to fix this.

[image]

This is what I have tried so far:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {


            var doughnutData = [
                {
                    value: 48.3,
                    color: "#81d7d8",
                    highlight: "#23c6c8",
                    label: "Accepted"
                },
                {
                    value: 20.7,
                    color: "#f58894",
                    highlight: "#d9534f",
                    label: "Denied"
                },
                {
                    value: 31,
                    color: "#f5c592",
                    highlight: "#f8ac59",
                    label: "Pending"
                }
            ];

            var doughnutOptions = {
                segmentShowStroke: true,
                segmentStrokeColor: "#fff",
                segmentStrokeWidth: 2,
                percentageInnerCutout: 45, // This is 0 for Pie charts
                animationSteps: 100,
                animationEasing: "easeOutBounce",
                animateRotate: true,
                animateScale: false,
                    fullWidth: true
            };

            var ctx = document.getElementById("doughnutChart").getContext("2d");
            var DoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(doughnutData, doughnutOptions);



        });
    </script>
```

In my HTML the respective section looks like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-content">
            <canvas id="doughnutChart" width="95" height="95" style="width: 95px; height: 95px;"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone who could point me to what I am missing here?

Comment: What is the `height` and `width` of your canvas item ? I wasn't able to [reproduce the error](https://jsfiddle.net/m4toaxf4/) with what you provided.

Comment: @tektiv Thanks for asking - I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the legacy Chart.js ***v1.x***, you don't have as many possibilities as in the ***v2.x***.

One simple way to fix your problem is to edit the style of your tooltips in your options. This won't change your default 95px of `height` and `width` for your chart :

```
    var doughnutOptions = {
        // ...
        fullWidth: true,
        tooltipFontSize: 10
    };
```

And will give [this result](https://jsfiddle.net/4r7r342k/).

Comment: Thanks, that's a perfect solution